# Idiomatic phrase for small type words at end of a document

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a phrase in English that that can be used in the following situation:

You read an article and from the title you understand that this is something positive, but if you read it all, very carefully, you will see that "small words" at the end reveal the reality.

The same situation is when signing contracts, when something negative for the customer is indicated in the end with small letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "small words" at the end (as the questioner put it) which contain some less positive information is colloquially called "the small print" in English.

Comment: It may also be called [fine print](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fine+print). Either phrase mostly has the contractual stipulation though and the basic idea is to try and deceive somebody into signing something they do not really agree to by making it hard to read and easy to miss altogether.

Comment: *Fine print* is more commonly used than *small print*, IMO. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=small+print%2C+fine+print&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmall%20print%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfine%20print%3B%2Cc0) supports my impression somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

In Minnesota (fly-over land) it's almost always the "fine print".  In fact, I don't think I've ever heard (do see it in print) "small print" used in conversations.

Comment: It could be a regional difference. In the UK, "small print" is very common - even in a semi-formal situation people discussing an agreement or contract will refer to the "small print"  in this way. If I heard "fine print", however, I would correctly guess the meaning from the context.