Something Unnecessary but Required by Agency
Something that is used by few but required by agency. For example, the directions on how to use Reddi-Wip (whipped cream in a canister) takes up most of the backside of a Reddi-Wip can, however, I would bet most people never read these directions. I bet the same could be said for the ingredients of consumables that could surely be replaced by a QR code. Unnecessary is a fit, however, it does not imply a requirement by agency.
Example sentence:

Unfortunately, the ________ verbiage can't be removed.


What does "required by agency" mean? You mean required by the government/law? And see also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260556/idiomatic-phrase-for-small-type-words-at-end-of-a-document https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40352/what-is-the-word-for-unnecessary-detailed-information https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302733/what-do-you-call-a-spoken-disclaimer-on-a-radio-tv-commercial

Ready-Wip? Do you mean Ready Whip? Ready Whip comes in a can, by the way. As the Brits say, this question is taking the piss. :)

@Lambie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddi-Wip

Please use the "edit" button to give a sample sentence showing how the word would be used. I'm genuinely uncertain which shade of meaning you're looking to emphasize: the legal/bureaucratic officiousness ("red tape"?) or the un-usefulness and opportunity for improvement. Voting to close until edited.

@AndyBonner - Thanks for the reply, I update the question.

Also, can you update the question to make the concept 'agency' clearer. Your example sentence and explanation don't make that clear. What is it about the instructions that have (or not) agency?

Are you specifically looking for an adjective modifying [obligatory] verbiage, or will a complete alternative noun (phrase) fit the bill? In some contexts, but not all, a legal disclaimer might fit the bill ("We make every effort to ensure our products contain no nuts, but we cannot guarantee they are 100% nut-free").

You'll find it is very necessary. It probably includes health and safety measures in order to cover companies from label-based lawsuits :  instructions not to place the can on an open fire,  not to freeze it, not to puncture it with an axe…

@Mari-LouA - Who would do anything related to that outside of Hollywood

The word “regulatory” serves, here:

The regulatory verbiage can’t be removed.

Since you’re specifically talking about a regulatory agency’s legal requirement, this word conveys more than “legalese” does. Legalese isn’t always required, someone might add it just to try to cover their butt, but regulations require the kind of message you’re talking about. It is “boilerplate” text, too, but that doesn’t explain why it can’t be removed.

Actually, I think "regulatory boilerplate" is the best permutation from all the suggestions so far. That's a link to half a dozen written instances of the collocation.

I think that the word you are referring to is "formality"
A formality is something that is done in accordance with a routine. In many cases, these routines are formally institutionalized by an organization, such as an agency. "Formality" also carries the connotation of being unnecessary.

I am going to go with legalese from the other answer only because using it in a sentience such as "...the legalese printed on the back of consumer goods." would convey the meaning better IMO than "...the formality printed on the back of consumer goods.". Sorry, my question and intended use was not stated. Thanks for this answer!

@RossBush: I shouldn't have closevoted and then posted an answer, so i've voted to reopen. But I doubt others will support that unless you edit your actual question text to include more information about the exact context where you want to use the sought term. Bear in mind that if you edit the question as requested, and it does get reopened, someone might come up with a better alternative!

Neither term exactly and only fits OP's context, but I might call it...

boilerplate
written text that can be reused in new contexts or applications without significant changes to the original

...because often nobody really cares exactly what the text means in any given context, so it's often just generic "one size fits all" information.
OR...

legalese
language used by lawyers and in legal documents that is difficult for ordinary people to understand

...because it's often a legal requirement that the text should include certain information (such as the worthless / meaningless "Terms and conditions apply" appended to many advertisements).

The two can be combined to give boilerplate legalese, obviously.
